# jquery incomplete animation on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I am working on a navigation system for my site. The idea is to display the content when the parent is hovered.

But, when content is hovered fast, the animation is incomplete and it stops in between.

The complete working and code is in the demo link below. Any suggestions on the changing the code will be helpful.

### DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vaakash/yH9GE/

> **When the "two" arrows are hovered at the same time (move fast from one
>   arrow to another) they stop and are incomplete**

The code I used is

```
$('.anpn-wrap').mouseenter(function(){           

    $wrap = $(this);
    $txt = $(this).find('.anpn-text');
    $cnt = $(this).find('.anpn-cnt');

    $txt.hide();
    $cnt.css({ 'opacity': 0, 'margin-top': '-50px', 'width': '200px' });
    $wrap.stop().animate({ 'width': $cnt.outerWidth() });
    $cnt.show().animate({ 'opacity': 1, 'margin': 0});

});

$('.anpn-wrap').mouseleave(function(){

    $wrap = $(this);
    $txt = $(this).find('.anpn-text');
    $cnt = $(this).find('.anpn-cnt');

    $cnt.show().stop().animate({ 'opacity': 0, 'margin-top': '-50px' }, function(){
        $cnt.hide();
        $wrap.stop().animate({ 'width': $txt.outerWidth() });
        $txt.fadeIn();
    });

});​
```

[image]

Comment: What is your desired behavior?  It's pretty standard to have a navigation item stop/reset it's animation on mouse leave.

Comment: What browser are you using when you see the undesired behavior? Have you confirmed it appears in several browsers and not just one in particular? I'd suggest at least IE, Chrome, Firefox and Safari (in no particular order). Including Opera would also be a good idea.

Comment: In Opera: I can't make it stop "in between". ...... correction ... I just tried a two-button shuffle ... it does indeed stop in between.

Comment: I tried in Opera, the animations are incomplete when "both" are hovered straight back at a time.

Comment: It's a "cross-talk" issue. Each button must currently in some way address the other button's animated elements. It's probably a question of getting the jQuery selectors right such that they animate only `this` button's elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not localizing `$wrap`, `$txt` and `$cnt`, they will be global, hence if a mousenter event occurs before an earlier mouseleave animation has finished, these vars will be overwritten and the callbacks in the first animation will address the other button's elements.

The solution is to declare `$wrap`, `$txt` and `$cnt` with `var`, in both handlers.

Try this:

```
$('.anpn-wrap').mouseenter(function() {
    var $wrap = $(this).stop();
    var $txt = $wrap.find('.anpn-text').hide();
    var $cnt = $wrap.find('.anpn-cnt').css({
        'opacity': 0,
        'margin-top': '-50px',
        'width': '200px'
    }).show().animate({
        'opacity': 1,
        'margin': 0
    });
    $wrap.animate({
        'width': $cnt.outerWidth()
    });
}).mouseleave(function() {
    var $wrap = $(this);
    var $txt = $wrap.find('.anpn-text');
    var $cnt = $wrap.find('.anpn-cnt').show().stop().animate({
        'opacity': 0,
        'margin-top': '-50px'
    }, function() {
        $cnt.hide();
        $wrap.stop().animate({
            'width': $txt.outerWidth()
        });
        $txt.fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what you want instead, but you can pass arguments to [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to force-complete the animation.

```
stop(true, true)
```

See this version: http://jsfiddle.net/yH9GE/2/

Comment: when the "two" arrows are hovered at the same time (move fast from one arrow to another)  , they stop.